# multiple full width horizontal block in pyrocms

Tags: pyrocms

I am pretty much new with pyrocms.

I have to build a page which will contain 4 blocks/section(lets call it block) and each block will be turned off/on based on a button click.(basically it' will be a slider).

Now I am thinking what will be the best way to build the multiple full width horizontal blocks inside the page.I can handle the sliding part.The block will contain dynamic text with background color/image(dynamic) or only a background image(dynamic) or the entire block can be 2 columns(width of 50% each).

Please suggest.

Comment: I suggest that you add a question to your text.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it.Can you please explain.Thanks

Comment: do you want something like what is on PYROCMS dashboard that sections have an anchor at upper right corner to show/hide??